# sort this list based on distance

Tags: python, list, sorting

i have the following function to calculate the distance

```
def Euclid_Distance(training_data, testing_data):
  sum = 0
  for i in range(0, len(testing_data)):
      sum += math.pow(training_data[i] - testing_data[i], 2)
  return math.sqrt(sum)
```

in KNN, how would i sort the list ls based on the distance?

```
def KNN(k, training_data, test_data):
  ls = []

  for train_data in training_data:
      distance = Euclid_Distance(train_data, test_data)
      ls.append({"distance: ": distance, "class": train_data[len(train_data) - 1]})
```

Comment: `ls.sort(key=lambda x: x["distance"])`

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the list by using sort function providing extra argument as distance.
Your KNN function will then look like

```
def KNN(k, training_data, test_data):
  ls = []

  for train_data in training_data:
      distance = Euclid_Distance(train_data, test_data)
      ls.append({"distance: ": distance, "class": train_data[len(train_data) - 1]})
  ls.sort(key=lambda x:x["distance"])
```